# in Word 2016: How to group all the authors under a single-color-single author so that other users will see it that way

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a document where many author editted it. Now, for the convenient of the external (third party) reviewer, I want to centralize all the auditing (of the many authors) into one author, plus, making all the editings in one color (whether adding text, deleting, etc). I do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make two copies of the file. Accepts all edits in one and reject all edits in another. Then compare them in MS Word as two versions to get a single file with all edits.

Comment: Thank you. Did that, for some reason, it kept the authors original names (even though I accepted all changes).

Comment: @erez80 Did the names of all authors stay or just one of them? In the first case, did you actually save the changed document to the disk after accepting all changes before comparing it with the original? In the second case, it could pick up the last author from the documents properties. When comparing the documents you have an option to change the name of the author of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to File > Info > Check for Issues. Uncheck all, except Document properties. Than run the check and click to remove the properties. At first, it will appear that nothing happened. Then save the document. That removes the properties, like authors, but keeps the edits.

If you need the document to be reviewed by the external party afterwards, you may want to restore tracking the changes as separate authors. Go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Privacy Options > uncheck the last option "Remove personal information from file properties on save" to stop it removing personal data on saving. Without that, all the information about the author of the edits will be removed on saving the document.

Answer (score 0):

Use Roman's method. Then if you need everything the same color, change your Track Changes options to show both deletions and insertions in the same color.

Since this is a user preference, it will not travel with the document. Create a pdf showing the tracked changes to preserve this. Send this, with the document, to your outside reviewer.

Then change your options back unless you want to continue with the same color for both.

I do not think this is worth doing, but you may disagree.